# Call celery tasks from different server

Tags: django, celery

I have a django app + redis on one server and celery on another server. I want to call celery task from django app.

My task.py on Celery Server:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks')
app.conf.broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

@app.task(bind=True)
def test():
    print('Testing')
```

Calling the celery task from Django Server:

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery()
celery.conf.broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
celery.send_task('tasks.test')
```

I am running the celery worker using this command:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
```

When i call the celery task from django, it pings the celery server but i get the following error:

> Received unregistered task of type 'tasks.test'. The message has been
> ignored and discarded.
> Did you remember to import the module containing this task? Or maybe
> you're using relative imports?

How to fix this or is there any way to call the task?

Comment: what you mean by celery server and django server? u have two servers for those?

Comment: Yes. I am processing heavy background tasks which are cpu intensive. So, I deployed two separate servers

Comment: if you deployed to two different servers, why you use localhost in both server?

Comment: I am testing it on local machine with two different projects. Redis is running at localhost

Answer (score 3):

Your task should be a shared task within celery as follows:

tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery, shared_task

app = Celery('tasks')
app.conf.broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

@shared_task(name="test")
def test(self):
    print('Testing')
```

and start celery as normal:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
```

Your application can then call your `test` task:

main.py

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery()
celery.conf.broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
celery.send_task('tasks.test')
```

Comment: I added the main.py code in Django views and its working fine. Is there any way to get the result of send task in the django views without getting timedout

Comment: You will need to configure a results backend first then you can use get() to retrieve the result.